# compare two file in unix using awk

Tags: unix, awk, compare

I need to compare two files. File1.txt and File2.txt in unix. The values present in File1.txt and not in File2.txt have to be written into diff.txt. I guess we can implement using awk only. Can anyone please guide me to achieve this?

File1.txt

```
apple
bat
cat
```

File2.txt

```
apple
cat
```

diff.txt

```
bat
```

Answer (score 5):

try this one-liner:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next}!($0 in a)' file2 file1 > diff.txt
```

Comment: This is by far my most frequently used one-line … +1 :) (though you forgot the end quote)

Answer (score 1):

```
diff file2 file1 | perl -lne 'print $1 if(/^\> (.*)/)'
```

Comment: +1: This is a good approach, but probably better to do something like `diff -u file1 file2 | sed -n '/^---/!{/^-/s/-//p}'`

Answer (score 0):

This is the job that "comm" was created to do:

```
comm -23 file1 file2
```

man comm for details. The caveat is that the input files have to be sorted, as yours are.